# Rails: Rspec View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to write a rspec file for my form.

My form looks like this, it has one nested form:

```
 <%= f.fields_for :uebungs do |builder| %>
  <%= render "uebung_fields", :f => builder %>
 <% end %>

 <div class="boxUebung">
   <div class="actions">
    <%= f.button "Hinzufügen" %>
   </div>

   <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
   </div>
</div>
```

I did this, but what to inserts in the it"" loop:

require "spec_helper"

```
describe "gastplans/_form.html.erb" do
it "show all fields" do

end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather recommend you to read firstly some articles about this complex topic. I should definitely read the official [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html).

Another great article is here:
http://everydayrails.com/2012/04/24/testing-series-rspec-requests.html

And of course, I can't forget on RailsCasts and its [episode about this topic](http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara?view=asciicast).
Finally, for further reading I would recommend you read the [Rspec book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356379).
Just search, Google is full of articles related to this topic.